# Order pick tracker with available hours

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p90L.png)Calculate time available per hour across midnight for a list of start and finish times

Hi all,

I have a spreadsheet I would like to create where I have start time and a finish time in columns a and b

Across the top I have times of the day 06:00, 07:00 etc in 1 hour increments

If a colleague start time is 19:00 and finish time is 05:00 they would have 1 hours available between them times but nothing else

I have a current sheet but it calculates over 1 for most of the cells

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So what are you using, what's wrong, and what did you expect.
You can post data as data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Also Google Sheets and Excel are different. Don't tag both; make a choice.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p90L.png

The above is the link to what I’m trying to do

Comment: But how to write that in a question using my hint

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using column C instead of columns A and B in your calculations, and also using sum function with just one value.

#### Solution (for copy-pasting)

If you want a formula that would output a number between 0 and 1 for employees availability in a specific hour, the following monstrosity would be a way to go:

```
=IF($A4<$B4,IF(HOUR(C$3)>HOUR($A4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($A4),1-MINUTE($A4)/60,0))-IF(HOUR(C$3)>HOUR($B4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($B4),1-MINUTE($B4)/60,0)),IF(HOUR(C$3)<HOUR($B4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($B4),MINUTE($B4)/60,0))+IF(HOUR(C$3)>HOUR($A4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($A4),1-MINUTE($A4)/60,0)))
```

Here is also a [demo Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgyqrwSUFxCzgrAhQxXXA8u4HgEHGwwLE5b2styZzO8/edit?usp=sharing).

#### Detailed explanation

There are many ways to shorten it, but since they require a lot more explanations this might be optimal to explain here, so let's start.

The outer most `IF` is simple, it just decides whether the availability crosses midnight or not since those two cases are quite different:

```
IF($A4<$B4,"Normal","Crosses midnight")
```

##### Normal

If availability doesn't cross midnight there are 3 cases for starting time that affect whether we chose 0, 1 or a fraction:

- starting time is after that specific hour > availability is 0,
- starting time starts somewhere within that specific hour > availability is a fraction based on the minutes,
- starting time is before that specific hour > availability is 1, until we pass finishing time.

Those subcases correspond to the first large `IF` in the `"Normal"` case:

```
IF(HOUR(C$3)>HOUR($A4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($A4),1-MINUTE($A4)/60,0))
```

After passing the finishing time, there are 3 more cases:

- finishing time is after that specific hour > availability stays 1,
- finishing time starts somewhere within that specific hour > availability is lowered to a fraction based on minutes,
- finishing time is before that specific hour > availability is lowered to 0.

Those subcases correspond to the second large `IF` in the `"Normal"` case, but since we are lowering the availability from 1, its subtracted from the value of first `IF`:

```
-IF(HOUR(C$3)>HOUR($B4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($B4),1-MINUTE($B4)/60,0)
```

##### Crosses midnight

If availability crosses midnight the mechanism is similar, we just add the values for starting and finishing time, instead of subtracting them. Starting from midnight we do as follows:

- finishing time is after a specific hour > availability is 1,
- finishing time starts somewhere within that specific hour > availability is a fraction based on minutes,
- finishing time is before that specific hour > availability is 0.

Hence:

```
IF(HOUR(C$3)<HOUR($B4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($B4),MINUTE($B4)/60,0))
```

When getting to the starting time we add the availability:

- starting time is after that specific hour > availability is 0,
- starting time starts somewhere within that specific hour > availability is a fraction based on the minutes,
- starting time is before that specific hour > availability is 1, until we get to midnight.

So, the last bit looks like:

```
+IF(HOUR(C$3)>HOUR($A4),1,IF(HOUR(C$3)=HOUR($A4),1-MINUTE($A4)/60,0))
```